# Clickhouse Error DB::Exception: Pos in empty own buffer, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below)

Tags: clickhouse

Could anyone help me with this error? I don't understand what it means and how to fix it.
Clickhouse version 21.7.2.7

I have several partitions in Kafka.
When I create a Kafka Engine table and attach a materialized view to it, I've got this type of error.
But interesting behavior is that the Kafka engine continues to ingest data from some partitions and skip another.

```
<Error> void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t): Code: 49, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Pos in empty own buffer, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0x8d35c1a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::PeekableReadBuffer::checkStateCorrect() const @ 0x106bc556 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. DB::JSONAsStringRowInputFormat::resetParser() @ 0x1078adf3 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. DB::KafkaBlockInputStream::readImpl() @ 0x1026fd2d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::IBlockInputStream::read() @ 0xf51faa4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::copyData(DB::IBlockInputStream&, DB::IBlockOutputStream&, std::__1::function<void (DB::Block const&)> const&, std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0xf542cf5 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::StorageKafka::streamToViews() @ 0x10264279 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(unsigned long) @ 0x10262e58 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::BackgroundSchedulePoolTaskInfo::execute() @ 0xf772a40 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::threadFunction() @ 0xf774ab7 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ? @ 0xf775834 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x8d76adf in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ? @ 0x8d7a3c3 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. start_thread @ 0x9609 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
14. __clone @ 0x122293 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
 (version 21.7.2.7 (official build))
```

Kafka engine

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.kafka_table
(
    `message` String
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'host:29092,host2:29092,host3:29092',
    kafka_topic_list = 'topic',
    kafka_group_name = 'group',
    kafka_format = 'JSONAsString',
    kafka_num_consumers = 3,
    kafka_max_block_size = 10000,
    kafka_poll_max_batch_size = 10000,
    kafka_thread_per_consumer = 1,
    kafka_handle_error_mode = 'stream';
```

Comment: Maybe, you have empty string `''` instead of empty JSON string `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LineAsString format in kafka_format = 'JSONAsString'
(see details https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/single/#lineasstring)
Possibly, your input format is not parsable to JSON (input contains \r or \n or something like this), try to use more similar input format like string or blob.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with data that had been placed in Kafka. It looked like

```
"{\r\n\t\"field_1\": \"value_1\", ..., \r\n\t\"field_n\": \"value_n\"\r\n}"
```

Hence, Clickhouse Kafka Engine couldn't parse it and commit offset, so this was a cause of big consumer lag. Changing the input format has fixed the problem but I have to add supplementary JSON validation in materialized view attached to the Kafka engine table.

correct SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.kafka_table
(
    `message` String
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'host:29092,host2:29092,host3:29092',
    kafka_topic_list = 'topic',
    kafka_group_name = 'group',
    kafka_format = 'RawBLOB',
    kafka_num_consumers = 3,
    kafka_max_block_size = 10000,
    kafka_poll_max_batch_size = 10000,
    kafka_thread_per_consumer = 1,
    kafka_handle_error_mode = 'stream';
```